# Entity Framework generating Script that runs with errors

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first

I am working on a solution using Entity Framework. I use Code First Work Flow to update my database by creating migrations. Everything works fine and now I want to deploy to production. I used `Update-Database -script -SourceMigration:InitialModel` from Package Manager Console to generate the DB script I want to run on the production database. Here's the part of the script file generated:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Projects] (
        [Id] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
        [Title] [nvarchar](max),
        [OwnerId] [int] NOT NULL,
        [StartDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
        [EndDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
        [ProjectStatus] [int] NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Projects] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
    )

    INSERT [dbo].[__MigrationHistory]([MigrationId], [ContextKey], [Model], 
    [ProductVersion])
    VALUES (N'201711231319470_AddProjectTableToDB', 
    N'ErdisERP_AmpleAdminTheme.Migrations.Configuration', A Large Random 
    String, N'6.1.3-40302')
    More SQL codes...
```

Here's the error produced `Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Invalid object name 'dbo.__MigrationHistory'.`

P.S: I am just starting out ASP.NET MVC5. I'll appreciate any pointers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you do not have the __MigrationHistory table. When you use `-SourceMigration:InitialModel` EF will use that as a starting point. If you want to tell EF to use a blank database as the starting point, use `$InitialDatabase` which will also include code to create __MigrationHistory :

```
Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration: $InitialDatabase
```